# Como hago para borrar valores basura?

Tags: c++, archivo, csv, read

Estoy haciendo un proyecto para aprobar una asignatura de la universidad en `C++`.  Esta, entre otras funciones inserta Hoteles en una `BBDD` desde un `.csv` pero añade valores basura.
Alguien me puede ayudar?

```
void BaseDeDatos::insertarTodosLosHoteles() {
ifstream archivo("ListaHotelesCSV.csv");
string l;
char delim = ';';
int numHabi;
float pNoche;

getline(archivo, l);
while (getline(archivo, l)) {
    stringstream stream(l);
    string CodHotel, Nombre, NumH, Localidad, Direccion, prN, codP, codB;

    getline(stream, CodHotel, delim);
    getline(stream, Nombre, delim);
    getline(stream, NumH, delim);
    getline(stream, Localidad, delim);
    getline(stream, Direccion, delim);
    getline(stream, prN, delim);
    getline(stream, codP, delim);
    getline(stream, codB, delim);

    char *sch = new char[CodHotel.length() + 1];
    copy(CodHotel.begin(), CodHotel.end(), sch);
    sch[CodHotel.length()] ='\0';

    char *sn = new char[Nombre.length() + 1];
    copy(Nombre.begin(), Nombre.end(), sn);
    sn[Nombre.length()] ='\0';

    char *sl = new char[Localidad.length() + 1];
    copy(Localidad.begin(), Localidad.end(), sl);
    sl[Localidad.length()] ='\0';

    char *sd = new char[Direccion.length() + 1];
    copy(Direccion.begin(), Direccion.end(), sd);
    sd[Direccion.length()] ='\0';

    char *snh = new char[NumH.length() + 1];
    copy(NumH.begin(), NumH.end(), snh);
    snh[NumH.length()] ='\0';

    char *spn = new char[prN.length() + 1];
    copy(prN.begin(), prN.end(), spn);
    spn[prN.length()] ='\0';

    char *scp = new char[codP.length() + 1];
    copy(codP.begin(), codP.end(), scp);
    scp[codP.length()] ='\0';

    char *scb = new char[codB.length() + 1];
    copy(codB.begin(), codB.end(), scb);
    scb[codB.length()] ='\0';

    sscanf(snh, "%d", &numHabi);
    sscanf(spn, "%f", &pNoche);
    insertarHotel(sch, sn, numHabi, sl, sd, pNoche, scp, scb);
}
archivo.close();

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`insertarHotel()` es una funcion que inserta un Hotel a la base de datos y tiene este codigo:

```
void BaseDeDatos::insertarHotel(const char *cd, const char *nom, int numH,
    const char *loc, const char *dir, float prec, const char *codP,
    const char *codB) {
char query[100];
sprintf(query,
        "INSERT INTO Hotel VALUES('%s','%s',%d,'%s','%s',%f,'%s','%s')", cd,
        nom, numH, loc, dir, prec, codP, codB);

cout << query << endl;
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, strlen(query), &stmt, NULL);
sqlite3_step(stmt);
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
}
```

Y el .csv que recibe no tiene ningun tipo de caracte especial ni nada
[image: CSV ListaHotelesCSV]

Comment: ¿Cuáles son los valores basura según tu? ¿Cuál sería el comportamiento esperado? Estando en C++ considera usar `string` en lugar de `char *`.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código de `insertarHotel`?

Comment: Revisa tu archivo origen de los datos que es mas factible que por ahí se estén colando esos datos que denominas "basura" , un carácter raro,  algún espacio, o que no traiga datos que complete la columna correctamente. el archivo .csv lo puedes revisar con el notepad de Windows como un archivo de texto plano, ahí podrás notar cualquier detalle.

Comment: @Cesarin Gracias por vuestra ayuda. Que tal viéndolo de esta manera?

Answer (score 0):

Tu programa no es que esté generando valores basura ... es que está leyendo líneas en blanco, o al menos esa es la impresión.

En principio debería bastar con comprobar si la longitud de la línea es igual a 0 o no. Si lo es, avanzas a la siguiente línea y listo:

```
while (getline(archivo, l)) {
    if (l.empty()) continue;
```

Si sucede que no son líneas en blanco sino que tienen algún espacio, puedes comprobar el length:

```
while (getline(archivo, l)) {
    if (l.length() < 5) continue;
```